Check content of SignaturePad
In my Android application I'm using com.github.gcacace.signaturepad.views.SignaturePad for capturing users signature. When user confirms his signature I want to check if the signature is not just a simple X or a short line.
Currently I get a transparent Bitmap from the SignaturePad like this:
FileOutputStream fos = getBaseContext().openFileOutput("mySign" + currentId + ".bmp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Bitmap signImg = signaturePad.getTransparentSignatureBitmap(true);
signImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);

Are there any Bitmap functions that can check what I want to do?
